# Pull data from paypal email into PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf, paypal

I have had a look online but couldnt find any information on this even though I feel it would be a regular question, I have a shop at the moment that has been built and runs via html code. The user purchases an item then I get an email from paypal with all the information (address, item etc).

I was wondering is there a way I can pull the information from the email and place it automatcially into a pdf delivery note? At the moment I copy and paste then send it to the warehouse however it would be great if I could get this process done automatically...

Comment: of course it's possible. what have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing so far I was just wondering what my options were... if it could be done via a php script or program etc

Comment: This all depends on your experience with PHP. There are libraries for parsing email inboxes. There are libraries for exporting content in string/html form to a pdf. put them together. bingo !

Comment: Look through the paypal developer docs. Sure this can be done with a php script but question is far too broad for this site which focuses on code implementation problems. Suggest focusing on accessing the paypal api to create a little dashboard and do it from there rather than focusing on the email itself

Answer (score 0):

[Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) is what you want to use for that.

Any time a transaction hits your PayPal account their server will POST all of the data about that transaction to a listener script on your server.  Your script receives that data and can process it accordingly, including updating your database, hitting 3rd party web services, or simply sending out email notifications with attachments.